# apache ignite thin client with index query

Tags: ignite

I am running to an issue when I am trying to query a cache which contains a java object key and a java object as value. I have a hydrator process which populates this cache independently.
This entire setup is done in K8s.

- infra setup
  my microservice is deployed in a different k8s cluster and the ignite cluster is setup in a different cluster hence microservice is connecting to the ignite cluster through the thin client.
  When I run this locally it works well, but when the microservice tries to retrieve from cache in the datagrid, I get the following error.
  `org.apache.ignite.client.ClientException: Ignite failed to process request [54]: com.xxx.xx.domain.xx.OfferProperty (server status code [1]) at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.convertException(TcpClientChannel.java:359) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.receive(TcpClientChannel.java:319) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.TcpClientChannel.service(TcpClientChannel.java:237) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.lambda$service$1(ReliableChannel.java:168) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.applyOnDefaultChannel(ReliableChannel.java:800) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.applyOnDefaultChannel(ReliableChannel.java:766) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ReliableChannel.service(ReliableChannel.java:168) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] [riq-offer-service-container]   at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.GenericQueryPager.next(GenericQueryPager.java:93) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] [riq-offer-service-container]   at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor$1.nextPage(ClientQueryCursor.java:93) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] [riq-offer-service-container]   at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor$1.hasNext(ClientQueryCursor.java:76) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0] [riq-offer-service-container]   at org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientQueryCursor.getAll(ClientQueryCursor.java:47) ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]` 
  I assume that since it's a thin client and classloading is not supported - how do we get around this problem.

When I perform an index query - I should be able to get the deserialized object through the index query.

Comment: Can you please provide additional details: what operation do you execute? Do you use SqlFieldsQuery? What error do you get on the server side?

Comment: I am trying to execute an index query - and offersCache is ClientCache<K,V>
QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<String, Offer>> offerQuery = offersCache.query(
                new IndexQuery<String, Offer>(Offer.class)
                        .setCriteria(eq("offerId",  offerId)));

        List<Cache.Entry<String, Offer>> offerQueryResult = offerQuery.getAll();
On the server side I dont see any error.


Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientServerError: Ignite failed to process request [44]: com.quotient.platform.domain.offer.Offer (server status code [1])